# How do you get the request data with socket.io with node.js and express?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

So I have this problem using express with socket.io. I think it is pretty self explanitory; I simply need to get the session and request parameter data to socket.io. This cannot be done on the client side as some rooms are going to be private. Any solutions?

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.join(ROOM ID)

  socket.on('send message', function(data) {
    NEED USER ID STORED IN session.user
  }
})

app.get('/:roomid', function (req, res) {
  //req.session.user = THE USER ID
  //req.params.roomid = THE ROOM ID
})
```

Answer (score 5):

Socket.IO 0.7.7~ introduces a new property on the socket called `handshake` this is the data that we gather when the client does it's initial handshake request. It contains the headers, ip and some other stuff.

This wiki https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Authorizing touches the subject lightly.

Comment: Still though, how would I get the request roomid to socket.io to join the room?

Comment: The sessions store has a `get` method that takes the sessiond id as argument, so you can get the sessionid from the cookie headers and feed it in the sessionStore.


But this does require you to do initialize the store manually and supply it in the options:


var store = new express.MemoryStore;
express.session({store:store});

and than in socket.io you can do store.get('sessionid', function (err, data) { // access your session here});

Comment: At least on my NodeJS, the "handshake" includes the query params of the call to socket.io: '... "url":"/socket.io/1/?t=1355054837418" ...', so I had to fetch the query-string params from the 'referer', for example, to get the "id" param: url.parse(socket.handshake.headers.referer, true).query.id